# Язык C, extern многомерных массивов

Tags: c, массивы, extern

Подскажите, почему следующий код:

file.c

```
#include "map.h"

int map[10][10];
```

file.h

```
#ifndef MAP_H

#define MAP_H

#include <stdlib.h>

extern int map[][];

#endif
```

Не компилируется с предупреждением:

```
error: array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае

```
int map[][]
```

У вас измерения с открытым(не отпределенным) размером. Так как доступ к элементам расчитывается как start + index*sizeofelements то необходимо знать размер элементов.

Элементы внешнего массива - это внутренний массив int[]. Размер не известен.

Вы можете опустить только внешний размер, все внутренние должны быть определены.

Comment: Разве нет способа объявить в хедере внешний двумерный массив, не указывая его размерностей?

Comment: @Максим Только, если вот в таком виде `extern int map[][64];`

Comment: Может быть, вы сможете мне объяснить, с чем связано такое ограничение?

Comment: А как компилятор сможет рассчитать обращение, скажем, к `map[2][15]`, не зная последнюю размерность массива? А он ее не знает, пока (гипотетически) не обратится к другой единице трансляции - но это уже уровень компоновки, а не компиляции...

Comment: Есть команда sizeof, которая должна отрабатывать для всех типов данных. Для массива без определенного размера она не сможет отработать. Соответственно компилятор не сможет понять размер массива и не будет знать как к нему обращаться. Можно сделать финт через int **map, и динамически выделять под него память, но тогда вам надо будет следить за всеми проблемами с неё.

Comment: Но ведь мы можем сделать extern int arr[]; Такой вариант считается корректным. То есть, для одномерного массива можно, а для многомерного - нельзя?

Comment: Именно, потому что тип одномерного массива - int, размер которого известен, а тип 2мерного - int[] - и этот размер не известен. ) Понимаете?

Comment: Кажется, понял, спасибо вам.